# Resetting/reverting a custom module's update 'N value'

Tags: updating

In my custom module's install file I have a `hook_update_N` function. Let's say it's `mymodule_update_7100`. However, I've noticed that I've done it wrong and I want to change a line of code within this function. Seeing as I've already run `updb`/`update.php` the changes won't be picked up and I'd have to rename it to either `mymodule_update_7101` or create a new function after it with that name. I'd really rather not have to do this, so I was wondering if there's a variable that tells Drupal exactly what "version number" a module is currently at and whether I can reset it to trick it into allowing me to run the update script again.

The actual effect the function has had on the database isn't important because it's just generating a taxonomy term that I can easily delete through the front-end afterwards.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `schema_version` column in the `system` table contains the version of the last successful update. Manipulate that value and you can re-test your update.

The `name` column is the machine name of the module, same as the info file is named.

This query will do the trick for you.

```
UPDATE system SET schema_version = XXXX WHERE name = 'name_of_module';
```

Answer (score 2):

Drupal 7 core's install.inc has the function `drupal_set_installed_schema_version($module, $version)`

Answer (score 1):

On drupal 8 it's in the table `key_value` under `value` where `name` is the name of your module.

Answer (score 1):

For Drupal 9 UpdateHookRegistry service (*update.update_hook_registry*) replaced functions in schema.inc [according to New UpdateHookRegistry replaces functions in schema.inc](https://www.drupal.org/node/2444417)

so now instead of `drupal_set_installed_schema_version($module, $version)` you can use `\Drupal::service('update.update_hook_registry')->setInstalledVersion($module, $version)`

Example using Drush:

```
drush eval '\Drupal::service("update.update_hook_registry")->setInstalledVersion("MODULE", "930N");
```

Answer (score 0):

Following on from the comment by @wranvaud for Ddrupal 8, the actual statement/command is `db_update('key_value')->fields(array('value' => serialize(nnn)))->condition('collection', 'system.schema', '=')->condition('name', 'your_module', '=')->execute();`
where nnnn is the schema version you want to revert to. The important bit is `serialize` because the value is a blob/binary field. This can be executed in a Devel module php form